# How to calculate the angular resolution of a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a Motorized Vertical drive optical mount  [8MKVDOM-1](https://www.standa.lt/products/catalog/motorised_positioners?item=300)

Based on the specification, the resolution is 1.25 um and the lead screw picth is 0.25mm. To translate the linear resolution to angular,

theta = d * 2* pi/D
where d = linear resolution, D is lead screw pitch.

I get theta = 31.41 mrad

Similarly, I performed a measurement where i shone a laser on the mirror mounted and measured the displacement on the screen at 20.852m. The displacement was 1.25cm. I moved the steps to be 20.

Based on these numbers,
theta = arctan(1.5cm/20.852m) = 719.35 urad.

for each step, 35.96 urad.

The motor has a microstepping [image: microstepping] of 256 so I am not sure, where to use the value. But the angular resolution doesn't match for with the specification one from the website. Where is this miscalculation coming from?